# Wordpress: remove %category% from URL's of specific posts (without plugins)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, categories

I got stuck with the subj. What I need is to remove the category name from URL's of this category posts.

For example:

> http://blablabla.com/articles/nice_shirt/

that turns to

> http://blablabla.com/nice_shirt/

Post URL's of other categories are to stay same.

What's the best way to do it? Try to rewrite URL in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Can you not just turn the post into a page? I would also recommend the wordpress stack exchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: It would be the last resort in my situation... I'd prefer to keep the same post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are steps for change the permalink

1)Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/

2)Next set your Category Base to /.

Once saved,you’ll see your URL changed to this format:http:/yourblog.com/quotes/

Comment: I need categories names in other categories posts (for example, I don't want posts in a blog category look like http://blablabla.com/post1/ instead of http://blablabla.com/blog/post1/